# get list of text in { } from a string

Tags: c#, list

I am look for a function that will take a `string` that has *placeholder* in it and generate a *list of the placeholders*. the placeholders are indicated by `{ }`.

**Example:**

```
"Good Morning {FIRSTNAME}, We are reaching out to inform you of your appointment with {INTERVIEWRE} on {APPTDATE} at {APPTTIME]. Please arrive by {ARRIVEBYTIME} and bring a copy of your resume.";
```

Expected return

```
["FIRSTNAME","INTERVIEWRE","APPTDATE","APPTTIME","ARRIVEBYTIME"]
```

There is also a chance there my be nested {}

```
"{FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}}"
```

I did have this as my attempt at the function. It does work but I know it is no where near efficient

```
public static List<string> GetInBrackets(string input)
{
    List<string> res = new List<string>();
    int bracketCount = 0;
    string tempStr = "";
    foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (bracketCount > 0)
        {
            tempStr += c.ToString();
        }
        if (c.ToString() == "{")
        {
            bracketCount++;
        }
        if (c.ToString() == "}")
        {
            bracketCount--;
            if (bracketCount == 0)
            {
                res.Add(tempStr.Substring(0,tempStr.Length-1));
                tempStr = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I know the ToString() isn't the best way to go. My issue is the placeholders are inserted by humans and they CAN make mistakes. This will eventually be used by some error handling code that will double check that these placeholders are valid and there are no nested placeholders.

Comment: And what should be result in  the case of nested placeholders?

Comment: @GuruStron if the input is "{FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}}" it should output "FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}"

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using regular expressions to match required placehlders:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

...

string text = "Good Morning {FIRSTNAME}, We are reaching out to inform you of your appointment with {INTERVIEWRE} on {APPTDATE} at {APPTTIME}. Please arrive by {ARRIVEBYTIME} and bring a copy of your resume.";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"\{(?<value>\p{L}[0-9\p{L}]*)\}")
  .Cast<Match>() // <- for old c# versions only 
  .Select(match => match.Groups["value"].Value)
  .ToList();
```

Pattern `\{(?<value>\p{L}[0..9\p{L}]*)\}` explained:

```
\{               - {
(?<value>        - group with "value" name
   \p{L}         - any Unicode letter
   [0-9\p{L}]*  - followed by letters or digits (zero or more)
)
\}               - {
```

**Edit:** If you are looking for an *old school* solution, you can use `Stack` for it:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> PlaceHolders(string text) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    yield break;

  Stack<int> starts = new Stack<int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
    if (text[i] == '{')
      starts.Push(i);
    else if (text[i] == '}' && starts.TryPop(out int from) && starts.Count == 0)
      yield return text.Substring(from + 1, i - from - 1);
}
```

Demo:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string text = 
  "Good Morning {FIRSTNAME}, try complex {OUTER{INNER{INMOST}}} and {SIMPLE}";

var result = PlaceHolders(text).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
FIRSTNAME
OUTER{INNER{INMOST}}
SIMPLE
```

Comment: after you have completed linkedin learning videos, your answers are more educative, sir. +1

Comment: I am getting the error of: 'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for "Select"
Also check the edit to the question

Comment: @Guy Cothal: please, do not forget to add `using Sistem.Linq;`; if you use an old c version you may want to add `.Cast<Match>()`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Linq is my best firend...but when you use the update here with "{FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}}", you only get "LASTNAME" instead of "FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}". I think I may have to do it old skool.

Comment: @Guy Cothal: I assumed that placeholder starts from letter and can contain digits and letters only, so `{ABC}`, `{abc123}` are placeholders, when `{a+b+c}`, `{1}` are not. In case of `{FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}}` only `LASTNAME` is a placeholder.

Comment: @Guy Cothal: if you are looking for an *old school* solution, which takes *nesting* into account, you can try using `Stack<T>`, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<string> GetPlaceholders(string input)
{
  var placeholders = new List<string>();

  // Regular expression pattern to match placeholders enclosed in curly braces
  var pattern = @"{([^{}]+)}";

  // Match all placeholders in the input string
  var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

  // Extract the placeholder names from the matches
  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
    var placeholder = match.Groups[1].Value;
    
    placeholders.AddRange(ExtractNestedPlaceholders(placeholder));
  }

  return placeholders;
}




private static List<string> ExtractNestedPlaceholders(string placeholder)
{
  var placeholders = new List<string>();

  // Regular expression pattern to match placeholders enclosed in curly braces
  var pattern = @"{([^{}]+)}";

  // Match all placeholders in the input string
  var matches = Regex.Matches(placeholder, pattern);

  // Extract the placeholder names from the matches
  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
      var nestedPlaceholder = match.Groups[1].Value;
      placeholders.AddRange(ExtractNestedPlaceholders(nestedPlaceholder))
  }

  // If there are no nested placeholders, add the placeholder itself
  if (matches.Count == 0)
  {
      placeholders.Add(placeholder);
  }

  return placeholders;
}



var input = "Good Morning {FIRSTNAME{LASTNAME}}, We are reaching out to inform you of your appointment with {INTERVIEWRE} on {APPTDATE} at {APPTTIME}. Please arrive by {ARRIVEBYTIME} and bring a copy of your resume.";
var placeholders = GetPlaceholders(input);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", placeholders)); // Output: "FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, INTERVIEWRE, APPTDATE, APPTTIME, ARRIVEBYTIME"
```

Updated to check for nested placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the "{" char and then trim the "}" chars out and write the string array to a string list like you want... Something like:

```
string startingText = "Good Morning {FIRSTNAME{LastName}}, We are reaching out to inform you of your appointment with {INTERVIEWRE} on {APPTDATE} at {APPTTIME}. Please arrive by {ARRIVEBYTIME} and bring a copy of your resume.".Replace("}", " ");
string resultText = string.Empty;
        
string[] chunks = startingText.Split('{');
        
for (int i = 1; i < chunks.Count(); i++) 
{
    resultText += (!chunks[i].Contains(" ") ? chunks[i].Trim() + "," : chunks[i].Trim().Substring(0, chunks[i].IndexOf(" ")) + ",");
}
        
resultText = resultText.Trim().TrimEnd(',');
resultText = string.Format("[{0}]", resultText);

//[FIRSTNAME,LastName,INTERVIEWRE,APPTDATE,APPTTIME,ARRIVEBYTIME]
```

To be honest though, you probably just want to leave each bit in the string array and work with the string array.

Comment: Splitting on `{`, the first two item in `stringBits` will be `"Good Morning "` and `"FIRSTNAME}, We are reaching out to inform you of your appointment with "`

Comment: I added to the original question...this breaks it a bit

Comment: @GuyCothal updated to show you something that will work but, as noted, depending on your use-case you probably would be better served to use an array object than the end string